# Change wp_query on the detail pages of each project depending on the option selected in the projects page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

In the projects page, where there is all the projects, there is an option (select option) to sort alphabetically and another to sort chronologically. When going to the detail of each project has a link to ' next project' and another link to 'previous project'. I wanted to ask if it is possible for the previous and next project to be sorted according to the selected option of the projects page.

Page of projects: http://alvarovarejao.com/designpublico/pt/projetos/

```
 <div class="row filterr">
<div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="ccc" class="alfabet" id="c1" value="1">
        <label for="c1">
            <?php 
                if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { echo " Alphabetical"; } else { echo " Alfabeticamente"; }
            ?>
        </label>
        <br>
    <input style="margin-top: 12px;" type="radio" name="ccc" id="c2" value="2">
        <label for="c2">
            <?php 
                if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { echo " Chronological"; } else { echo " Cronologicamente";} ?> 
        </label>
        <br>
    <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="radio" name="ccc" id="c3" value="3" checked="checked">
        <label for="c3" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <?php 
                if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { echo " Random"; } else { echo " Aleatoriamente";} 
        ?>
        </label>
</div>
</div>



<div class="text">

<div id="primary" class="row projects projects-filter">

        <?php

        if(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 4) == '127.' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1') {
            if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { $project = 47; } else { $project = 49; }
        } else {
            if (get_locale() == 'en_US') { $project = 69; } else { $project = 71; }
        }


    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $project ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile; 
    else :
        endif;
        ?>

</div>
</div>

<div class="text2" style="display: none;">
    <div id="primary" class="row projects projects-filter">



        <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC', 'cat' => $project ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    else :
        endif;
        ?>

</div>
</div>

<div class="text3" style="display: none;">
    <div id="primary" class="row projects projects-filter">



        <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC', 'cat' => $project ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();


            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    else :
        endif;
        ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any other way but to run a separate query for the next and previous projects, apparently a custom `wpdb` query. Refer to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73194/66571)